# Maximal ideal in ring Z

Tags: abstract-algebra

In wikipedia it says:

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers the maximal ideals are the principal ideals generated by a prime number.

But I think $(2)\subsetneq(2)\cup(3)$, which means that $(2)$ is not maximal ideal?

What's wrong with my statement?

Comment: $(2)\cup (3)$ isn't an ideal since it isn't a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Note: 1)$Z$ is a principal ideal domain. 2) if $I_1$ and $I-2 $ are two ideals $I_1 \cup I-2$ is not necessary an ideal and in your case it is not

Comment: Oh, I understand. I forget that ideal has to be additive subgroup of Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(2)\cup (3)$ is not an ideal: $2+3\notin (2)\cup (3)$.

Answer (score 3):

If by $(2)\cup(3)$ you mean $(2,3)=(2)+(3)$, i.e. the ideal generated by $2$ and $3$, notice that it is the whole ring $\mathbb{Z}$, since it contains $1$.